# R Roxygen: Did not find imported function in example

Tags: r, namespaces, documentation, roxygen2

In a function of a package I'm writing, I want to create a cox ph model from the formula and data. Nothing spectacular, and the function works as intended. Internally, I call the `coxph` function, which in turn calls the `Surv` function (both from the survival package).

When adding an example to the roxygen header, I get the following error message upon testing:

> Error in Surv(time, status) : could not find function "Surv"

In the roxygen header, I have declared the import (went with the functions only but also tried the entire package), and the NAMESPACE file clearly lists the import. When loading the package to a clean workspace (without survival loaded), the function also works (and doesn't if I remove the import).

How can I ensure that the example has the correct namespace available? I'd hate to use `\dontrun`.

Abbreviated function (not intended to run, not syntactically correct, just a simplified version of what's happening for context):

```
#' @importFrom survival coxph Surv
build_cox_model <- function(params) {
cox_form <- basecamb::build_model_formula(params)
cox_model <- survival::coxph(data, cox_form)
}
```

Extended error message:

```
data <- survival::lung
build_cox_model(data, 'time', 'status', c('age','sex'))
Error in Surv(time, status) : could not find function "Surv"
Calls: build_cox_model ... eval -> <Anonymous> -> model.frame.default -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

Comment: Your abbreviated illustration uses invalid syntax. `build_cox_model()` is defined as a function with one parameter, yet four parameters are passed in the example. How do you assemble the `formula` parameter for `survival::coxph()`?

Comment: If `formula` is passed by the user, it will be evaluated in the calling environment which is usually the global environment. However, if the formula is defined inside the function body of `build_cox_model()`, there should be no issues. Check out the examples in `?as.formula` for more details.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my post to clarify that a) the abbreviated function is pseudo-code used to broadly outline the implementation rather than accurately represent the syntax, and b) the formula is designed in the function body via another package (that is also declared in imports and imports Surv itself)

Comment: Of note: The error message clearly states that not the formula construction, but its evaluation is the problem. Also, if I start a completely clean session, load the package and execute the example in console, it runs smooth like butter (without the entire survival package being attached)

Comment: How and where the formula is created matters because formulas always have an environment attached. If the attached environment doesn't "see" the symbol `Surv`, this creates this exact error message.

Comment: Thank you - I understand the general concept, but I'm having trouble understanding how exactly it breaks in this context.
Seeing that the formula is defined through calls originating in the function body, shouldn't the final environment have inherited the pointer to `Surv`? Especially since that function also lists `Surv` as an import? And if it isn't, why does it work when I execute it in the console after loading the package into a clean workspace?

Comment: This is in fact really weird. Yes, the pointer to `Surv` should in fact be inherited the way you described. I guess you are getting the errors with `devtools::check()`? What happens if you install the package and then run `R CMD check` in the Terminal?

Comment: A quick fix might be to explicitly set the environment of the formula to your package environment. Something like `environment(cox_form) <- parent.frame()`.

Comment: No luck: R CMD check produces identical results; setting the environment for cox_form in the function body also did not fix the problem

Comment: Hmm. Other potential workarounds would be to [re-export](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/04/re-exporting-the-magrittr-pipe-operator/) the `Surv` function or dropping the dependency to `basecamb`. But I can't tell you if either of them will actually work.

Comment: Thanks. Dropping the dependency also doesn't fix the problem. I have not tried reexporting the function and opted to use `\dontrun{}` for the example since I run a unit test with identical code (which passes). Unfortunately, I'll need to do the same with all functions relying on that function (even if they also import `Surv`) or else their examples fail as well (while passing identical unit tests)